# How to include full e-mail address in "ftp://" line in Windows folder?

Tags: windows, ftp

As an easy way to interact with an FTP server, Windows supports typing URLs in the Address section in any folder.

Problem is, the FTP server I need to connect to requires a full e-mail address, and the following isn't accepted because of the two @'s:

> ftp: // me @ somewhere.com:mypasswd @ ftp.somewhere.com

(I had to add spaces because SU doesn't allow links to FTP servers)

Does someone know the right format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick search came up with:

Special characters in FTP URL have to be hex encoded to operate without any conflicts. And the hex conversion will look as following:

```
ftp://user%40gmail.com:password@some_ftp_server.com
```

where `%40` is the hex value (0x40) of `@` character.

`%2E` is for `.` if needed in  your browser.

Comment: Thanks, I found it seconds before you posted :-) Turns out it's only a good solution to download files, as Windows doesn't provide a way to select a file to upload (eg. right-click). I'll write a simple FTP client, then.

Comment: Yeah, good luck.